# C programming in linux 'open() read() write()' : Failed to create and open file

Tags: c, linux

I am studying this youtube tutorial by ShellWave which learns you how to program in C on a Linux device and for some reason am getting stuck at lesson #024 : [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dP3N8g7h8gY&list=PLypxmOPCOkHXbJhUgjRaV2pD9MJkIArhg&index=24)

My code is the following (I used the same as in the video) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char buf[14];
        
    //write
    
    fd = open("myfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);
    
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to create and open the file. \n");
        exit(1);
    
    }
    
    write(fd, "Hello World!\n", 13);

    close(fd);
    
    //read
    
    fd = open("myfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
    
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to open and read the file. \n");
        exit(1);
    
    }
    
    read(fd, buf, 13);
    buf[13] = '\0';
    
    close(fd);
    
    printf("buf : %s\n", buf);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The terminal shows output "Failed to create and open file". So I think I am using the open() wrong or maybe it has to do with my Ubuntu version?

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong?

I tried changing the order of the flags and tried to change the mode to 0777 and 0700 with no success.

There was a Permission Denied error. For some reason the "myfile.txt" was locked.
*chmod u=rwx,g=r,o=r myfile.txt*  command worked for me. Thanks everyone for the quick help.

Comment: When a function fails, use e.g. `perror` to print a message instead, or use `strerror(errno)` to get a string describing the error. And always check what `read` and `write` returns, as well.

Comment: I changed myfile.txt to myfile to try to fix the error, forgot to change it back again

Comment: perror() says Permission denied

Comment: What is the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) when you try to run the program? *How* do you try to run the program?

Comment: Home/Documents is the directory. The file is called "foo.c"
I try to run the program with 'gcc -o foo foo.c' and then './foo'

Comment: If you think the solution could be helpful for others, then please post an actual answer, and mark it as accepted. If you *don't* think it might be useful for others, then you should probably delete the question (if it's possible with upvoted answers, and if not post your own answer). If you post an answer, please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) first.

Answer (score 1):

The only visible differences I can spot are from the this line:

```
fd = open("myfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);
```

You didn’t include the ‘.txt’ on the end of the file name in this instance.

The video has this line listed as:

```
fd = open("myfile.txt”, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600);
```

The O_CREAT and O_WRONLY were the wrong way around, though I don’t know if this would change anything.

*Edit: Thank you kind replier, been informed the order does not matter.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: The order for bitwise OR (`|`) doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I think the problem is not here though. I have not permission for some reason to create a file in my Directory.

Answer (score -4):

My terminal shows the different outut :

```
gcc t.c -Wall -Wextra
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:11:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   11 | int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      |          ~~~~^~~~
t.c:11:26: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   11 | int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      |                    ~~~~~~^~~~~~
a@zalman:~/Dokumenty/t/t1$ ./a.out
buf : Hello World!
```

For me the program works. So maybe your compilation failed ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an "answer" you can tell that in the comments.

Comment: @Stranger My answer has 3 downotes. The question was closed because " is not reproducible or was caused by typos.". So is my answer ( So maybe your compilation failed ?) good or not ?

Comment: @Baum mit Augen ( I ask you because you are moderator) My answer has 3 downotes. The question was closed because " is not reproducible or was caused by typos.". So is my answer ( So maybe your compilation failed ?) good or not ?